# Layout change on Ctrl-Down/Up: a way to solve "QWERTY-shortcuts in Dvorak layout"

Tags: 14.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dvorak

There are several related questions:

- [Is there any way to use QWERTY's keyboard shortcut position while the Dvorak layout is active?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143573/is-there-any-way-to-use-qwertys-keyboard-shortcut-position-while-the-dvorak-lay)
- [Dvorak layout with Qwerty hotkeys (Dvorak — Qwerty Ctrl)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35803/dvorak-layout-with-qwerty-hotkeys-dvorak-qwerty-ctrl)
- [Why do some shortcuts no longer work when using an alternate keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137855/why-do-some-shortcuts-no-longer-work-when-using-an-alternate-keyboard-layout)
- [Why don't shortcut keys change when keyboard layout changes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2647/why-dont-shortcut-keys-change-when-keyboard-layout-changes)

But no one gives working solution for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there any way to do this?

- in Russian (or whatever non-Dvorak) layout <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed down switches to Dvorak
- when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is released then layout comes back to Russian

Comment: Try Synergy its a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

I created some XKB configuration files to enable Dvorak-Qwerty for Ubuntu 14.04 that works as Qwerty when pressed down Control, Alt or Super key.

[-Dvorak-Qwerty for Linux- GitHub](https://github.com/ZeptByteS/dvorak-qwerty)

and I can customize it for Russian. did you mean that you want to use Dvorak-shortcuts in Russian layout? not Qwerty-shortcuts in Russian?